# How do I convert a variable containing a percentage to a number in LESS, but leave plain numbers alone?

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

In a LESS mixin, I have an alpha value that I'd like to convert to a plain number (0.xx) even if it is given as a percentage (xx%). I've found the percentage() function to convert a number to a percentage, but percentage(xx%) returns "xx00%" and dividing by 100 makes 0.xx into 0.00xx, which is no good either. All the "if-then" statements that I could find in LESS invlove making a new scope, so while I could detect the "%", I couldn't pass that information back into a variable to use it.

How do I go about converting a percentage to a number if and only if it is a percentage?

Answer (score 3):

While you can use JS within Less to achieve the desired effect, a better approach would be to use the built-in [`ispercentage()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#type-functions-ispercentage) and [`isnumber()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#type-functions-isnumber) type functions to check whether a variable value is a number or a percentage or neither and then output the value accordingly.

```css
.percentlike(@var) {
  & when (ispercentage(@var)){ /* is input value a percentage */
    alpha: unit(@var / 100); /* unit() strips the % symbol */
    /* you could also use the replace function like below
      @percentage: @var / 100;
      alpha: replace(~"@{percentage}", "%", "");
    */
  }
  & when not (ispercentage(@var)) and (isnumber(@var)){ /* not percentage but is a number */
    alpha: @var;
  }
  & when not (ispercentage(@var)) and not (isnumber(@var)){ /* neither */
    alpha: ~"NaN";
  }
}

div#div1 {
  .percentlike(20%);
}
div#div2{
  .percentlike(0.2);
}    
div#div3{
  .percentlike(a);
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
div#div1 {
  alpha: 0.2;
}
div#div2 {
  alpha: 0.2;
}
div#div3 {
  alpha: NaN;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I get the impression this is the more "LESS-y" way to do it. My biggest issue with that was that there was another mess of guards that depended on another value, so it would have ballooned exponentially.

Comment: @SuperFLEB: Oh I see. Anyways no worries mate, it would atleast help future readers who may have similar needs. Your question was well written and an interesting one so I thought it deserved a pure Less answer :)

Comment: Btw. using `unit()` to convert `*%` to `*` is not a hack. This is actually the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: replace(~"@{value}", '%', '');

Comment: Wouldn't that give me, for instance "20" instead "0.2" for "20%"?

Comment: Not, this expression just takes string representation of "value" variable and  replace '%' char to nothing (i.e. just remove '%', nothing more).

Comment: Okay, I'm looking for something to make it so both "20%" and "0.2" passed into the mixin can be converted to the same value of 0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's an end-run, but I found a solution. You can use backticks to run arbitrary JS in LESS, so I just did...

```
.percentlike(@var1, @var2) {
  -percent-property: ~`"@{var1}".match(/%$/) ? parseFloat("@{var1}") / 100 : parseFloat("@{var1}")`;
  -decimal-property: ~`"@{var2}".match(/%$/) ? parseFloat("@{var2}") / 100 : parseFloat("@{var2}")`;
}

div {
  .percentlike(20%, 0.2);
}
```

Which, as desired, yields...

```
div {
  -percent-property: 0.2;
  -decimal-property: 0.2;
}
```